# Power switch in electronics in Europe

Tags: switches, button, networking, power-management

Are there any requirements towards user electronics working in Europe stating that they need to have on/off switches?

I am asking especially regarding networked devices. I have seen a lot of unmanaged ethernet network switches without power buttons (device is powered after DC plug is attached and can be turned off only by disconnecting the cable).

I would appreciate any references.

Comment: it seems that you have answered your own question

Comment: Does it move in any shape or form the user can access?

Comment: @winny what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no such requirement (no EU law mentioning it).

The most relevant piece of EU legislation I know of is [here](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02008R1275-20170109) in its consolidated version.

There may be other relevant legislation I don't know about; I am not a lawyer 8-).

Answer (score 1):

for industrial devices below 3680W or 16A a main power switch is optional.
So far I don't know - like ocrdu said in his answer - any rule for commercial grade devices.
if no other standard applys, network equipment should not require a power switch